# List collection Loop

Tags: c#, list, linq

Language c# , Visual Studio 2015

```
public class UserDTO
    {
        public string UserID {get;set;}
        public string UserName {get;set;}
        public string ManagerName {get;set;}
        public string ManagerEmail {get;set;}
    }
```

I get List input as below

```
List<UserDTO> lstUsr = new List<UserDTO>();
lstUsr.Add(new UserDTO { UserID = "A1", UserName = "AXZ" });
lstUsr.Add(new UserDTO { UserID = "B1", UserName = "BYZ" });
```

i have a method to get the ManagerEmail and ManagerName and the input is UserID

i need to loop lstUsr and update the ManagerEmail and ManagerName for each UserID in the same List.

Now i create multiple List and obtain result. i wanted to know if it will be efficient, it be done using the same List ? Appreciate pseduo code help

```
string ShiftUserID = string.Join(",", lstUser.Distinct().Select(a => a.UserID));
private List<UserDTO> GetManagerDetail(string ShiftUserID )
        {
            List<UserDTO> lstMgrDetail = new List<UserDTO>();
            UserDTO oUser = null;
            string sMgrName;
            string sMgrMobile;
            string sMgrEmail;
            string[] sUserADID = sShiftUserADID.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
            foreach (string sADID in sUserADID)
            {

                    oUser = new UserDTO();
                    ADHelperUtility.GetManagerDetail(ShiftUserID , out sMgrEmail, out sMgrName);
                    oUser.ManagerName = sMgrName;
                    oUser.ManagerEmail = sMgrEmail;
                    lstMgrDetail.Add(oUser);
                }

            return lstMgrDetail;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself yet? What was the result? Did it work?

Comment: "Now i create multiple List and obtain result" - please edit the question to include how you do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Iterate through the list as you'd expect and set the values:
Something like:

```
foreach(UserDTO user in lstUsr)
{
   string managerName;
   string managerEmail = GetManagerInfoByID(user.UserID, out managerName); // Returns email and send out managerName. You could use an object here instead, just showing this for demo purposes.

  user.ManagerName = managerName;
  user.ManagerEmail = managerEmail;
}
```